High storage usage with Samsung Galaxy S8 and image / image quality retention
My Samsung Galaxy S8 alerted me that the storage was critically full and may result in data corruption or failure to boot.
I immediately deleted some apps to free up 2GB. But I am worried that it may have taken steps without my knowledge, such as clearing / disabling recently deleted (an issue as my screen was bugging and may have deleted by ghost touch without me knowing) or automatic lossy compression (an issue as I require some images to not have any compression artefacts). I am also concerned that the 2GB free may be a result of these optimisations, or whether it is a reasonably consequence of the handful of apps I deleted, plus the alert being given when there was already some storage free.
I have two main questions:

are either of those issues likely?
how can I check whether these optimisations have been implemented?


To my knowledge, there is no such mechanism. However, if there was and it had already made these changes then it is too late.
If the phone supports an SDcard, then

Put a genuine, branded one in.
Change the paths for photos and screenshots to the SDCard.
Move over existing photos and screenshots over
Copy over any other files such as videos

